# Error when starting up new RSelenium server

Tags: r, phantomjs, rselenium

This error has occurred twice in my attempts to web scrape through RSelenium. When freshly opening up my Rstudios project I'm able to start up an RSelenium server.

```
rsD <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"))
remDr <- rsD[["client"]]
```

But when I'm finished and manually close the opened browser and stop the server via;

```
remDr$closeServer()
```

I can't create a new RSelenium server. I don't know if this is because it's not possible to create more then 1 server at a time, or I simply don't know how to correctly stop or drop a server.

This is the resulting error I get when trying to create a new RSelenium server after closing the first server. I've also tried differing browsers like firefox and phantomjs with the same error result.

```
> rsD <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"))
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  : 
  Selenium server signals port = 4567 is already in use.
```

There's clearly something obvious i'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the latest RSelenium rsDriver has a bug in command close().

Check this https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/228. At the end there is a workaround you could use.